# emacs suggests to recover-file, but I missed it: how to make it prompt?

Tags: emacs, crash

When emacs notices a crash, on next open of the file it "suggests" M-x recover file. But that only flashes up briefly, so I missed it this morning :(  I went on editing, and lost last evening's work.

Is there a way to make that suggestion a prompt that must be responded to before it continues?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` to file an enhancment request. Try to be clear about just what behavior you would like, when you would like it, etc. (step by step).

Answer (score 1):

The warning message comes from the function `after-find-file`. I don't find an option to control this, but you can define a function to do something similar:

```
(defvar already-in-prompt-for-auto-save nil)

(defun prompt-for-auto-save-recovery ()
  (if (and (not buffer-read-only)
           (not already-in-prompt-for-auto-save)
           (file-newer-than-file-p (or buffer-auto-save-file-name
                                       (make-auto-save-file-name))
                                   buffer-file-name)
           (y-or-n-p (format "%s has auto save data: do you want to recover it? "
                              (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))))
      (let ((already-in-prompt-for-auto-save t))
         (recover-this-file))))
```

and then install it as a hook.

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'prompt-for-auto-save-recovery)
```

This is lightly tested code--I extracted what looked like the relevant parts of `after-find-file`--but maybe it will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried similar to this.  Only problem is that the same function will be executed when you hit `(recover-this-file)` as the function will run `find-file-hook`s again.

Comment: Also, `recover-this-file` already asks if you want to recover the file so the `y-or-n-p` is possibly redundant.

Comment: @KindStranger You're right. I think that's fixable, but I need to brush up on my elisp.

Comment: I've fixed the problem with recursive invocations now. The `y-or-n-p` probably is redundant, but I left it in since it's easy to remove.